# Wait for Async function before returning

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, message-queue, messaging

I am creating a messaging system and I am facing a problem. I need to Publish a message and wait for the response before returning the Publish function.

This is what my functions look like

```cs
public async Task<bool> Publish(int ClientId, string msg){
    ...
    // Wait and check if the client the message was sent to respond
    // if that does not happen within 5 seconds, return false, else true
}

private async Task MessageIntercept(int ClientId, string msg){
    // Intercepts all messages
    ...
}
```

*Both of these functions are on the server and the MessageIntercept task is automatically run whenever  a message is sent (including the one sent with the Publish method). I can send a message from my asp.net website project by calling on the server project's Publish function mentioned above*

Basically what i want to be able to do is call `bool Success = Publish(1,"This is a test")` and be able to determine whether or not the message was successfully sent, that the client understood and revived the message within 5 seconds.

This is what happens step by step:

1. I send a message from the server to the device with `Publish`
2. The message is intercepted by the `MessageIntercept` method (which I do not really care about, but the code is written so that all messages are intercepted)
3. The client receives and handles the message
4. The client responds, and the message is intercepted in `MessageIntercept` which is where I would like to verify the message before returning the `Publish` method

Example Message;

Server Message:

```
{
    ClientId: 13,
    msg: "Hello World"
}
```

Client Response:

```
{
    ClientId: 13,
    msg: "{Success: true}"
}
```

`MessageIntercept` intercepts all messages, including the request just send which should be ignored due to it beeing a request not a response. However once the client responds with a message would I like to tell the Publish method that the response has been successfully completed and then return true. Else if the client does not respond within 5 seconds it should presume false.

Comment: What's the importance of MessageIntercept here? I'm assuming the "Publish" makes the server request, so this entire logic would be from Publish perspective.

Comment: @Erndob the MessageIntercept is needed because it the messages from the client is not run by the Publish Mehod

Comment: How is the `MessageIntercept` method called? Is it awaited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing for Publish to wait on, so you need to add a notification hook. An event like "OnMessageIntercept" makes sense to me.

You can then wait on a Task that will be completed by a call to the notification hook.

```
public async Task<bool> PublishAsync(int clientId, string msg)
{
    // Wait and check if the client the message was sent to respond
    // if that does not happen within 5 seconds, return false, else true
    var messageRecievedSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    void intercept(object sender, MessageInterceptEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.ClientId == clientId)
            messageRecievedSource.SetResult(clientId);
    }
    OnMessageIntercept += intercept;
    // EDIT
    // var completed = Task.WaitAny(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), messageRecievedSource.Task) > 0;
    var completed = await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), messageRecievedSource.Task);
    OnMessageIntercept -= intercept;

    // EDIT
    // return completed;
    return completed == messageRecievedSource.Task;
}

event EventHandler<MessageInterceptEventArgs> OnMessageIntercept;

private async Task MessageIntercept(int clientId, string msg)
{
    OnMessageIntercept?.Invoke(this, new MessageInterceptEventArgs(clientId, msg));
    // Intercepts all messages
}

class MessageInterceptEventArgs
{
    public MessageInterceptEventArgs(int clientId, string msg)
    {
        ClientId = clientId;
        Msg = msg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(msg));
    }

    public int ClientId { get; }
    public string Msg { get; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this code asynchronous allowing multiple messages to be sent at once ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I misunderstood when you asked "before returning the Publish function" to mean you wanted Publish to wait until it confirmed the response before returning at all. See if my edit behaves as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Have honestly been stuck on this for way to long!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a helper method such as this:

```
public static async Task<bool> WaitFor(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    return await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            if (await WaitFor(MyAsyncMethod(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                Console.WriteLine("First await completed");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("First await didn't complete");

            if (await WaitFor(MyAsyncMethod(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
                Console.WriteLine("Second await completed");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Second await didn't complete");
        }

        public static async Task MyAsyncMethod()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }

        public static async Task<bool> WaitFor(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            return await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task;
        }
    }
}
```

For your `Publish()` method, the call may look like this:

```
if (await WaitFor(Publish(1, "msg"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
    ...
```

However, be aware that the disadvantage of using this approach is that if the timeout is exceeded, then any exceptions thrown by the task will not be observed.

If you need to handle any exceptions that may occur after you've given up waiting for the task, you could pass an exception-handling delegate like so:

```
public static async Task<bool> WaitFor(Task task, TimeSpan timeout, Action<Exception> handleException)
{
    var wrapperTask = task.ContinueWith(
        t => handleException(t.Exception.InnerException), 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    return await Task.WhenAny(wrapperTask, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task;
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    if (await WaitFor(
        MyAsyncMethod(), 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        exception => Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + exception.Message))
    )
        Console.WriteLine("First await completed");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("First await didn't complete");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can't this logic just be inside of publish method?

Comment: @Erndob Yes, of course - but if you're using this logic more than once it would be better to encapsulate it in a helper method. It also doesn't then violate SRP.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, how would I use the `WaitFor` method to verify and wait for the client's response in `MessageIntercept` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, sorry, know it has been a while, after reading your code example again I have come to a understanding that in your example you are waiting for the Publish method, however what I which to do is to wait for the MessageIntercept to complete which might or might not run, this should be done before returning the Publish mehod since I am in need of verify that the message was successfully recived and handled on the client side. How would i do that ?

Comment: @Steinar It's a bit difficult to answer this, since it's not clear exactly what the control flow is. Can you use the `WaitFor()` for the `MessageIntercept()` call?  Is it possible for you to write a compilable console app that demonstrates what you mean?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I just added more information to the question. Did that clarify things? And no, I cant use the `WaitFor()` on `MessageIntercept` since it is called from the MQTTnet library, and i dont know when it is called

Answer (score -1):

It is an async function, you will have to do "something" in case a result has returned. For example, you could fill in a hidden field value and read it from codebehind again. Or fire another async function and trigger a codebehind method. 
To be able to write something after a response, you have to listen to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run an async function synchronously you can use the following code in the `System.Threading.Tasks` library

`Task.Run(async () => await { async method here }).Result`

This will cause your asynchronous methods to become blocking, and your code will not continue until you have a response back.

Within your async method you can add a timeout `Thread.Sleep(5000)` or iterate over the result within the async function (perhaps with a stopwatch if you to avoid Thread.Sleep).

Answer (score -3):

```
bool Success = await Publish(1,"This is a test")
```